# Bubble Plots in R not displaying

Tags: r

I was attempting to follow a tutorial
to create a bubble plot of school district proficiency rates.

### Data

[shapefile of school districts (Census2010.shp)](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByHQd1ckVHrSYVB4QmNtUWktTGM&usp=sharing)

[District level data](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByHQd1ckVHrSdkdlbUsyREtrZms/edit?usp=sharing)

### Code

reading in data

```
dist <- read.csv('/Users/Path/to/District.csv', header = T)
state <- readShapePoly('/Users/Path/to/Census2010')
```

merge shapefile and district data

```
GA <- state
GA@data <-
    merge(GA@data, dist, by.x="NCESID", by.y="NCESID", all.x=T, sort=F )
```

creating bubble plot

```
plotvar <- GA@data$CCRPI
nclr <- 8
plotclr <- brewer.pal(nclr,"PuRd")
max.symbol.size=12
min.symbol.size=1
class <- classIntervals(plotvar, nclr, style="quantile") #Some school districts did not report data
colcode <- findColours(class, plotclr)
symbol.size <- ((plotvar-min(plotvar))/
    (max(plotvar)-min(plotvar))*(max.symbol.size - min.symbol.size) + min.symbol.size)
plot(GA)
GA.cntr <- coordinates(GA)
points(GA.cntr, pch=16, col = colcode, cex = symbol.size)
points(GA.cntr, cex = symbol.size)
```

Though the resulting map is just hollow school district outlines. What am I missing here?

Comment: +1 for reproducible spatial data and an interesting R problem.

Answer (score 2):

This code seems to work. You cannot use merge on an sp dataframe object. Merge resorts the dataframes during its operation breaking the rownames and the internal relationship in the resulting sp object. I changed the code to use readOGR in rgdal to read the shapefile. You were also using some R internals as objects (i.e, dist, class). This confuses R and often causes errors.

I am using version(s) R 3.0.1, classInt 0.1-19, RColorBrewer 1.0-5, rgdal 0.8-9, and sp 1.0-9

Note: if you omit dividing by pi the bubbles are far too big to plot.

```
    require(sp)
    require(rgdal)
    require(RColorBrewer)
    require(classInt)

    setwd("D:/TEST/Bubble")
      sdist <- read.csv(paste(getwd(), "District.csv", sep="/"), header = T)
      state <- readOGR(getwd(), "Census2010")
        GA <- state

    # Merge sp dataframe
    merge.sp.df <- function(x, y, xcol, ycol) {
      x@data$sort <- 1:nrow(as(x@data, "data.frame"))  
        xdf <- as( x@data, "data.frame")
         xdf <- merge(xdf, y, by.x=xcol, by.y=ycol) 
           xdf <- xdf[order(xdf$sort), ]
             row.names(xdf) <- xdf$sort
          xdf <- xdf[,- which(names(xdf) == "sort")]     
        x@data <- xdf  
       return(x)
    }

    GA <- merge.sp.df(GA, sdist, "NCESID", "NCESID")   

    # create bubble plot
    plotvar <- GA@data$CCRPI
    nclr <- 8
    plotclr <- brewer.pal(nclr,"PuRd")
      max.symbol.size=12
      min.symbol.size=1

    qclass <- classIntervals(plotvar, nclr, style="quantile") 
      colcode <- findColours(qclass, plotclr)

GA@data$symbol.size <- ((GA@data$CCRPI-min(GA@data$CCRPI,na.rm=TRUE))/(max(GA@data$CCRPI,na.rm=TRUE)-
                         min(GA@data$CCRPI,na.rm=TRUE))*(max.symbol.size - min.symbol.size) + min.symbol.size)/pi
      pt.pch <- rep(16,dim(GA)[1])  
        pt.pch[which(is.na(GA@data$symbol.size))] <- NA

plot(GA)
  points(coordinates(GA), pch=pt.pch, col=colcode, cex=GA@data$symbol.size)
    legend("topright", legend=names(attr(colcode, "table")), pch=16, 
           col=unique(colcode)[2:nclr+1])
```

Comment: thanks for taking a stab at this! I was trying to replicate your code, as I agree that the merge function is not ideal for this task. When i get to the readOGR function, I keep getting a "error in readOGR... missing layer" message. I re-downloaded the shape files to make sure nothing was missing to no avail. Am I missing a package?

Comment: Addendum. At R 3.0.2 and sp 1.0-14 there is now a merge function that works on sp class objects. You just call the function as merge and it recognizes an sp class object.